# Concatenar variáveis no template Django

Tags: python, django, lista, django-templates, concatenação-de-string

Fala galera, bom dia, estou com um problema. Estou percorrendo uma `lista` porém quero `concatenar` minha lista que estou chamando no `template` como `{{ list }}` e `{{ forloop.counter0 }}` pra que no meu for só seja exibido `1` item da lista por vez e não ela toda

***views.py:***

```js
def user_donations(request):
    donations = Donation.objects.all().filter(donor_id=request.user.id)

    donationItem = DonationItem.objects.all().filter(donation__donor_id=request.user.id)
    list = []

    for item in donationItem:
        list.append(item.material.name)

    content = {'donations':donations, 'list': list}
    return render(request, 'user-donations.html', content)
```

***html.py:***

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content%}
<section class="user-donations">
    <div class="register-header-desktop">
        <h2>Minhas doações</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="container register">
        <div class="donations-list">
            {% for donation in donations %}
            <div class="modal">
                <div class="confirm-school-name">
                    <span>{{ donation.created_at }}</span>
                    <span>De: {{ donation.donor }}</span>
                    <span>Para: {{ donation.school }}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="list-itens">
                    <span>{{ list.forloop.counter0 }}</span>
                    <span></span>
                </div>
                <div class="confirm-delivery">
                    <span></span>
                </div>
                <div class="arrow">
                    <img src="{% static 'images/arrow-down-icon.png' %}" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
{% endblock %}
```

Porém da forma que estou tentando não esta dando certo, alguém consegue me ajudar ?

Comment: Você quer rodar um `for` iterando sobre os itens?

Comment: exato @ThiagoLuizS, pro exemplo nessa `{{ list }}` eu tenho 3 itens, quero concatenar com o `{{ forloop.counter0 }}` para que cada vez que meu `for` principal rodar quando chegue na `{{ list }}` seja adiciono um número para que ele acesse um índice do vetor da `list` ex: primeira volta`{{ list.0 }}` segunda volta `{{ list.1 }}` e assim sucessivamente. saca ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pra resolver o problema eu fiz da seguinte forma:

1º criei uma `@property`:

`@property
    def items(self):
        return self.donationitem_set.all()`

depois na ***views.py:***

```js
def user_donations(request):
    donations = Donation.objects\
        .filter(donor_id=request.user.id)\
        .filter(confirmed=True)\
        .all()

    content = {'donations': donations}
    
    return render(request, 'user-donations.html', content)
```

e na ***user-donations.html:***

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content%}
<section class="user-donations">
    <div class="register-header-desktop">
        <h2>Minhas doações</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="container register">
        <div class="donations-list">
            {%for donation in donations%}
            <div class="modal">
                <div class="confirm-school-name">
                    <span>{{donation.created_at}}</span>
                    <span>De: {{donation.donor}}</span>
                    <span>Para: {{donation.school}}</span>
                </div>
                {% for item in donation.items %}
                <div class="list-itens">
                    <span>{{item.quantity}} {{item}}</span>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
                <div class="confirm-delivery">
                    <span></span>
                </div>
                <div class="arrow">
                    <img src="{% static 'images/arrow-down-icon.png' %}" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</section>
{% endblock %}
```

Dessa forma eu consegui fazer o que eu estava precisando

Answer (score 0):

Basta você iterar os itens sobre a lista utilizando um `for` que o mesmo se encarregará de trazer um item por iteração sem que seja necessário uma váriavel para indexação.

Por exemplo para criar uma lista no template do `Django` podemos fazer assim:

```
<div class="list-itens">
    <ul>
        {% for item in list %}
            <li class="item">{{ item }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: o problema de eu usar um `for` dessa forma é que ele me retorna os 3 itens da lista todos de uma vez, no meu caso, eu tenho 3 doações sendo que cada doação tem um único item que é uma raquete e usando um `for` na lista ele vai me retornar os 3 items doados em cada doação, parecendo que cada doador doou 3 raquetes

Comment: `4 de Outubro de 2018 às 18:47
De: admin@admin
Para: pudim@escola.com
Raquete Raquete Raquete
` @ThiagoLuizS

Comment: por isso que estava querendo concatenar a minha lista com um {{ forloop.counter0 }} pois dessa forma resolveria o meu problema, "creio eu skaoskaosko" pois quando eu acesso a lista dessa forma `{{ list.0 }}` ele me retorna só o primeiro item da `array`, e se pra cada loop eu tiver um `i++ do counter` talvez resolvesse meu problema, manja ?